# Focus to MgsBox when Excel is not active

Tags: excel, vba, focus, msgbox

I have checked related questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27301378/msgbox-focus-in-excel) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832966/how-do-i-bring-focus-to-a-msgbox) but the solutions there do not seem to solve my problem.

I am running a VBA script on my computer. The script takes a few minutes to execute and while waiting I am checking other things in my computer. To get my attention once the script has finished running, I have included a `MsgBox` at the end of my script. However, because Excel is not active/selected when the script finishes, I cannot see it - only when I reactivate/select Excel.

**How can I bring into focus the `MsgBox` when Excel is not active?** I have already tried the following tweaks but they do not work:

- **ThisWorkbook.Activate**:

  ```
  ...
  ThisWorkbook.Activate
  MsgBox "..."
  ...
  ```
- **AppActivate()** (this command threw an error):

  ```
  ...
  AppActivate("Microsoft excel")
  MsgBox "..."
  ...
  ```

Comment: User a userform and See Gareth's answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24733377/excel-useform-how-to-hide-application-but-have-icon-in-the-taskbar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about playing a sound when the program finishes?
Place this declaration at the top of a standard code module, above any procedures existing there.

```
Public Declare Function Beep Lib "kernel32" _
              (ByVal dwFreq As Long, _
               ByVal dwDuration As Long) As Long
```

If you place this procedure in the same module you may not need it to be public. Adjust pitch and duration to your preference.

```
Sub EndSound()
    Beep 500, 1000
End Sub
```

Then place the procedure call at the end of your program.

```
Call EndSound
```

I suppose you might use a more elaborate sound - may I suggest a couple of bars from Beethoven's 5th? Modify the *EndSound* procedure. [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/PlaySound.aspx) has more on this idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
```

Comment: I have just tried this but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Minimize excel and them execute the code.what happen?

Answer (score 0):

***Disclaimer***: This is not my code and I do not know who the author is. I had this code in my database.

Put your code in `Sub Sample()`. I have shown where you can insert your code. Once the code is run, Excel will flash 5 times. you can change this number by changing `Private Const NumberOfFlashes = 5`

Paste this in a Module.

```
Option Explicit

Private Type FLASHWINFO
    cbSize As Long
    Hwnd As Long
    dwFlags As Long
    uCount As Long
    dwTimeout As Long
End Type

Private Const FLASHW_STOP As Long = 0
Private Const FLASHW_CAPTION As Long = &H1
Private Const FLASHW_TRAY As Long = &H2
Private Const FLASHW_ALL As Long = (FLASHW_CAPTION Or FLASHW_TRAY)
Private Const FLASHW_TIMER As Long = &H4
Private Const FLASHW_TIMERNOFG As Long = &HC
Private FLASHW_FLAGS As Long

Private Declare Function LoadLibrary Lib "kernel32" _
Alias "LoadLibraryA" (ByVal lpLibFileName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function GetProcAddress Lib "kernel32" _
(ByVal hModule As Long, ByVal lpProcName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function FreeLibrary Lib "kernel32" _
(ByVal hLibModule As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function FlashWindowEx Lib "user32" _
(FWInfo As FLASHWINFO) As Boolean

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Const NumberOfFlashes = 5

Private Function APIFunctionPresent(ByVal FunctionName _
   As String, ByVal DllName As String) As Boolean

    Dim lHandle As Long
    Dim lAddr  As Long

    lHandle = LoadLibrary(DllName)
    If lHandle <> 0 Then
        lAddr = GetProcAddress(lHandle, FunctionName)
        FreeLibrary lHandle
    End If

    APIFunctionPresent = (lAddr <> 0)

End Function

Sub Sample()
    '
    ' Put your code here. Once that code finishes, Excel will FLASH
    '

    Dim udtFWInfo As FLASHWINFO

    If Not APIFunctionPresent("FlashWindowEx", "user32") Then Exit Sub

    With udtFWInfo
       .cbSize = Len(udtFWInfo)
       .Hwnd = Application.Hwnd
       .dwFlags = FLASHW_FLAGS Or FLASHW_TRAY
       .uCount = NumberOfFlashes
       .dwTimeout = 0
    End With

    Call FlashWindowEx(udtFWInfo)

    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to probably to create a userform instead then set the focus to this when it initialises.

Code in the userform to show as modal:

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "User32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName _
    As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "User32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, _
    ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long

Private Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1
Private Const SWP_NOMOVE = &H2
Private Const FLAGS As Long = SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE
Private Const HWND_TOPMOST = -1

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim hwnd As Long: hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, Me.Caption)
    If hwnd > 0 Then SetWindowPos hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, FLAGS   ' Set Modal
End Sub
```